# Store the array elments based on checkbox checked?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, checkbox

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal. I am displaying my check boxes in a for loop.

Here I am getting the all values in an array, but I want store the array elements based on the check box checked.

```
<?php 
    $j=0;
    $arr = Array();
foreach($collection as $data) {  
    $mageid=$data['mageproductid'];
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($mageid);
    $productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');       
    $checkeven=0;
        $arr[$j]=$products->getId();
        //echo $arr[$j];
    $j++;
} ?>
```

My checkbox code:

```
 <form id="check_all" action="" method="POST" name="check" >
<input type="checkbox" class="multid[]" id="<?php echo $products->getId();?>"  value="checked" />  </form>
```

What do I have to do in order to get checked values in my array? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: a checkbox get posted only if its checked

Comment: Yeah @Arun I want only checked values

Comment: thats in $_POST['multid']

Comment: can you please give full code ?

Comment: Jithesh code has the logic

Answer (score 1):

Use input name attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" name="multid[<?php echo $products->getId();?>]" value="checked" />
```

No in you php code, check if multid[yourProductId] is set, and store them if it is set.

```
<?php 
$j=0;
$arr = Array();
foreach($collection as $data) {  
$mageid=$data['mageproductid'];
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($mageid);
$productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');       
$checkeven=0;
$arr[$j]=$products->getId();
if(!empty($_GET['multid['.$arr[$j].']']))
  its checked, do something.
//echo $arr[$j];
$j++;
} ?>
```

Comment: I would put the `$products->getId();` into value so if the checkbox is checked it would output array with the IDs as values not as keys

Comment: Yeah Ok but nothing doing this one.

Comment: @Jithesh Thanks for your code Some thing wrong near to if() condition

Comment: if(!empty($_GET['multid['.$arr[$j].']'])) {
  $arr1[$j] = $products->getId();
  //echo $arr1[$j];
  }   i wrote like this inside if() but nothing is storing $arr1[]

Comment: var_dump($_GET) to see if the params are passed along.

Answer (score 0):

After submiting the form you can get an array of checked products with `$_POST['multid']`

Comment: Thanks @DeiForm I'm going to try this one

Comment: See my Edit And can you please give little more code for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use javascript? Try this one.
HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnCheckedIDs" value="" />
```

Before submit, on submit button's client click, Javascript:

```
var CheckedIDs = "";
for each checkbox
    if(document.getelementbyid('multid1').checked)
        CheckedIDs = CheckedIDs + document.getelementbyid('multid1').id;
document.getelementbyid('checkboxID') = CheckedIDs;
```

In PHP, you can use this comma seperated string `$_POST['hdnCheckedIDs']` to get the IDs of checked chekboxes.